# Test assumptions Log-Logistic AFT Model

Tags: statistical-significance, survival, cox-model, kaplan-meier, accelerated-failure-time

I'm considering adopting a Log-logistic Accelerated Failure Time (AFT) model for my analysis. Initially, I contemplated using the Cox Proportional Hazards (PH) model; however, the PH assumption was not met by my dataset. My preference for the log-logistic distribution stems from its possession of a non-monotonic hazard function. This aligns well with the characteristics of my time-to-event data, as its histogram exhibits an initial increase followed by a decrease.

My primary objective behind using the Log-logistic model is to conduct inference. I intend to incorporate numerous covariates within the model and subsequently perform inference on their coefficients.

My understanding indicates that the log-logistic AFT model doesn't depend on the PH assumption, but rather relies on the Proportional Odds (PO) assumption. Additionally, as it is a parametric model, I think I would have to test for the suitability of the chosen distribution.

By reading several articles online, I found the following:

- "The log-logistic assumption can be graphically evaluated by plotting ln(1 − Sˆ(t))/(Sˆ(t)) against ln(t) where Sˆ(t) are the Kaplan–Meier survival estimates. If survival time follows a log-logistic distribution, then the resulting plots should be a straight line of slope p."

However, I am wondering if this graphical evaluation will suffice when dealing with a model that has numerous covariates (both continuous and categorical ones).